# Laravel: a given number of models (download codes) in a single controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am building a feature which generates a given number of download codes and popupates the DB table with them. So with this link `downloadcodes/generate/10?type=1` I want to create 10 entries in my table.

The controller method looks like this:

```
    public function generate($quantity)
    {


        $codetype = Input::get('type');

        
        XXXX{    // ITERRATING LOOP from 1 to 10 

            $object = new DownloadCode;

            $object->type = $codetype; 
            $object->code = [string-of random-6-digits];
            $object->save(); 

        }

        return $quantity. " codes generated". $codetype;

    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: that should get done with a POST request not GET query params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to receive this number with a variable inside the route

```
Route::get('generate/{entries}','YourController@generate');
```

You can send it as follows

```
{{route('path.to.route.generate', 10)}}
```

Then you can insert that into a loop

```
public function generate($quantity , $entries)
{

    $codetype = Input::get('type');

    
    for($i = 0; $i < $entries; $i++) {    
        $object = new DownloadCode;

        $object->type = $codetype; 
        $object->code = [string-of random-6-digits];
        $object->save(); 
    }


    return $quantity. " codes generated". $codetype;

}
```

Comment: I would promote using named routes and this `[Controller::class, 'method']` syntax for new Laravel comers. And emphasize the bad practice of doing 10 separate **create queries** instead of grouping them.

Comment: @medilies Can you explain how queries are grouping 
Thanks

Comment: something like this https://3v4l.org/

Comment: @EslamNassr I have one issue. The name `object` is the same for all iterations. So the function writes new objects in an infinite loop. 20 000 per 10 seconds in my testing environment.